# TCP socket: Why BufferedReader.readLine() get NULL?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a classic Java client/server app, where client and server exchange messages by a TCP connection.

When one elemement, let's call it Receiver (no matter if client or server), has to receive a message, it listens and waits for a message coming from the other element, let's call it Sender.
The receiver implements it by the following code:

```
BufferedReader myBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mySocket.getInputStream()));
receivedMessageCompleto = myBufferedReader.readLine();
```

The sender, after some time, will send a text message implementing the following code:

```
String messageCompleto = "whatever text";
String packetSend = messageCompleto + '\n' ;  
DataOutputStream myDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mySocket.getOutputStream());
myDataOutputStream.writeBytes(packetSend );
```

The probelm is:
in some cases "myBufferedReader.readLine()" get null value, but I'm quite sure that the sender didn't send a message NULL.
The question is: why?

According to my understanding the Receiver should remain blocked until it receives something (let's consider that timeout is set to infinite), then "myBufferedReader.readLine()" should return a value only when something arrives. The point is that I'm sure that the sender didn't send a null message.

Any idea???

Thank you very much in advance
Fausto

Comment: What is the behavior if the receiver is blocked in `readLine` and the sender closes the socket?

Comment: HI, before to post this issue, I had already read that "A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached"; but in my case I have a try that catchs the cases when the sender is killed or close the socket, so I can exclude those cases. What I don't understand is: if I'm the receiver and I'm blocked waiting a TCP packet, if the sender doesn't send anything, if the socket is alive, why the end of stream has been reached?

Comment: The `null` return value indicates that the socket connection is not alive.  There are a number of reasons that a TCP stream can be terminated independently of either application calling `close` explicitly.  Are you sure that the sender side of the connection has not closed?

Answer (score 2):

```
public String readLine()
                throws IOException
```

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>   of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>   followed immediately by a linefeed.

Returns:

> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any
>   line-termination characters, **or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached**

Basically you get `null` if the underlying stream hits EOF.

Answer (score 1):

As it says in the [documentation for the readLine method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--):

> **Returns:**
>       A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been
>   reached

So, in your case, end-of-stream has been reached. Probably, the remote end of the socket was closed.